# C - Measure Function Time Execution

Tags: c, function, time, execution, measure

I want to measure elasped time for insertion_sort function. But, the result is 0.0000000 second. What can I do? I tried other time libraries.Unfortunatelly, it didn't... Thanks.    I writed again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) 
{
  int number=1;
  if(number == 1)
  {
     struct timeval start, end;
     gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

     for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
     {
     insertion_sort( kelime, n );   
     }
     gettimeofday(&end, NULL);

     printf("Elapsed time is %.10f",(end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec)-   (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec));
 }
```

Comment: Look at the `rdtsc` intrinsic.

Answer (score 2):

`time` only has seconds granularity. Whereas your code is likely to be microseconds or milliseconds at worst. Use `gettimeofday` instead which has microsecond granularity.

But note that both `time` and `gettimeofday` gives you wall time. If you want CPU time `clock` can be used.

Comment: I tried it. But, I didn't work code. What should I do?

Comment: Error] 't0' undeclared (first use in this function)
[Note] each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
[Error] 't1' undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: Show all the code. You haven't declared `t0` and `t1` in that code snippet. If that is indeed all your code then what else did you expect if not a compile error?

Comment: You need to declare t0 and t1 as struct timevals. Note that Windows doesn't have this function. You could use clock, but for Windows, the ticker only runs at 64hz, so only 15.625 ms resolution. You could use [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) but that's Windows only.

Comment: `%.10f`. The fields are not floats but longs (usually). Try `%ld`.

Comment: You can't have tried what I suggested. `%ld` does not result in any decimal places so you cannot have gotten "0.00000000" if you had tried what I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation and printing is:

```
 printf("Elapsed time is %.10f",
        (end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec) -
        (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec));
```

You are trying to print an integer value with a floating point format; this is not going to lead to happiness.  Assuming that the integer arithmetic does not overflow, then you can use:

```
 printf("Elapsed time is %.6f",
        ((end.tv_sec * 1000000 + end.tv_usec) -
        (start.tv_sec * 1000000 + start.tv_usec)) / 1000000.0);
```

which will give you a floating point value to print with the floating point format.  There's no point in requesting 10 decimal places when `gettimeofday()` supports only 6 (and 6 decimal places is the default, but explicitness is often good).

You could also use:

```
 printf("Elapsed time is %.6f",
        ((end.tv_sec * 1000000.0 + end.tv_usec) -
         (start.tv_sec * 1000000.0 + start.tv_usec)) / 1000000);
```

The key point is to make sure that enough of the computation is done in floating point arithmetic.

Comment: @Mr.Gurbuz: try sorting 5,000 elements instead of just 5.  Or be bold and go for 50,000, or even 500,000.  Don't go much higher or you can run out of stack space (I am not certain you'll be safe at 500.000 if you're on Wijndows).  Basically, sorting 5 elements does not take long enough to register.